# How to ensure whole data was sent? sendto (udp socket) Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

First of all, I know the difference between TCP and UDP, and I know, that it's possible that some packets can be lost while using UDP.

However, when we assume that I designed a protocol with some simple ACK's for UDP, how can I ensure that I sent / received whole data?

For instance, with TCP sockets it's quite simple:

Receive:

```
def recvall(sock, n): 
    i = 0
    data = ""
    while i < n:
          data += sock.recv(1)
          i += 1
    return data
```

And send: `sock.sendall(msg)`.

How something similar should be done while using UDP sockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want ensure that your client receives all data, use TCP.  UDP is not meant to be used in cases where you need to ensure data integrity.  Only use UDP when it is acceptable to have dropped packets.

Now that being said, you can check if the client received all the data by putting sequence numbers in your UDP packets.  Your client could then check each incoming packet's sequence number and compare it against the last sequence number it saw.  If `current_packet_sequence_num != last_packet_sequence_num + 1` then you can assume your client did not receive all data.

Comment: According to [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/83550), choosing TCP vs UDP is not about integrity, it's about you are _streaming_ data or  sending _messages_, so just saying "use TCP" is simple and wrong without understanding of the protocols' nature.

Comment: Just because no packets are dropped, does not mean that data integrity is assured. A packet could be corrupted, or be received out of order. TCP will handle this for you, UDP will not. Additionally, in your seqnum proposal, it allows the possibility where the last packet is dropped, and the client won't notice. It also does nothing if the UDP packets are corrupted, which you can check by looking at the UDP checksum